# Powershell: Find out if NUMA is configured and how many CPUs are assigned to each NUMA node?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, numa

Using Powershell, how can I find out if my server has NUMA enabled and how many CPUs are assigned to each NUMA node?

Update:

I found out [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.affinityinfo.numanodes.aspx) that the microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server object object has an affinityinfo field. However, that field doesn't exist in my server object in Powershell when I create it (SQL Server 2005 on Windows XP).

Update:

It appears that the affinityinfo field only exists in SQL Server 2008 R2 and later.

Answer (score 1):

There are APIs available that will get you this information but they are unmanaged which means they are not easily callable from PowerShell (.NET). In order to call these directly you have to use the `Add-Type` cmdlet to compile C# code into an in-memory assembly which you would then instantiate or invoke a static method from. I have an [example](http://andyarismendi.blogspot.com/2011/10/powershell-set-secureautologon.html) of what this looks like on my blog.

Writing the C# is the tricky part because there is a lot of unfriendly looking code associated with it, check out this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972437/pinvoke-for-getlogicalprocessorinformation-function). If you are familiar with C#, you might be able to adapt this to what you want. If not Mark has a tool called [Coreinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722) that looks like it will get you the information you are looking for. It actually calls the same unmangaged API that the linked p/invoke code does ([GetLogicalProcessorInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683194.aspx)). You can just call this from PowerShell and process its STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that native OS APIs in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 for working with more than 64 logical processors are available in .NET, you can have a look to [.NET Support for More Than 64 Processors](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/07/25/net-support-for-more-than-64-processors.aspx). This guy use to write a .NET wrapper for OS APIs, you perhaps use that in PowerShell.

Comment: Why would I need to work with more than 64 logical processors?